# Removing one data element (value) at a time from variable and performing function in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, data-manipulation

I am attempting to write code in R that permits me to:

1. Remove the first data element (value) from a variable (column) within a larger data frame.
2. Run a function on the full data frame (with the data element from step 1 removed).
3. Repeat this process for the remaining data elements in the column.

I've tried the following code and have run it without receiving errors. However, it is clear from the results that the data elements are not being successively removed as desired.

For context, my data frame (df) is 50x18 and the function that I am attempting to run from step 2 is a multiple imputation function. Here is my code:

```
procedure <- function(x) {
  x <- NA
  mice(df, m = 5, maxit = 5, method = "norm", pred = pred_matrix, seed = 2019)
}

results <- lapply(df$variable, procedure)
```

As desired, this code produces a list with 50 sets of output. However, it appears to perform the procedure 50 times on the same exact data frame. Thus, my question: **Why isn't my code looping through each element in the data variable and removing it before running the procedure?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) Where in the code exactly you are mentioning to remove one value? 2) Do you have dataframe with name `df` or `df_mice`? 3) You pass `x` in the function but don't use it anywhere.

Comment: The data frame should be called ```df``` (I made the appropriate edit to the original post). My intent with the ```lapply``` function was it would go through each element of ```df$variable``` and apply the procedure (first removing the data value and then implementing the ```mice``` procedure)

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to achieve and your code does not conform with what you are describing. Do you want the dataframe to "shrink" by one row with each iteration?

Comment: Not to shrink. Just for the value in a cell to become missing.